# ylabel covered in graph with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmax=10.5, xmin=-5.5,
    ymax=7.8, ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    title=AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM,
    xlabel={\(a \in \{t_s\}_{s=1}^6\)},
    ylabel={\(\mathfrak{f}_{a}\)},
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=south,},
    xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        ]
\addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
    {(-4,2) (-2,6) (1,3) (2,5) (8,3) (9,7)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}$$
\end{document}
```

the output is:

[image]

I have the following *problems*:

1. `ylabel` is covered!
2. there is not the zero in axis x!
3. graphically unit of measurement in axis x and units of measurement in axis y are different!

How Can I resolve the problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an attempt where `ylabel` was changed to `mathbf` because I use minimum packages required.

A1: Change the parameter of cs:xx in

```
every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.2)}
```

A2: Use

```
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
```

Or  instead of `axis lines=middle`, which assumes intersection will happen. To get xtick label 0  use what follows. (Also see 2nd image)

```
axis y line=middle, 
axis x line=bottom,
```

A3: Use

```
axis equal image=true,
```

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmax=10.5, xmin=-5.5,
    ymax=7.8, ymin=0,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left, 
    axis equal image=true, 
%    axis x line=middle,
%    axis y line=middle, 
    title=AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM,
    xlabel={\(a \in \{t_s\}_{s=1}^6\)},
    ylabel={\(\mathbf{f}_{a}\)},
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.2)},
        anchor=south,},
    xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        ]
\addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates
    {(-4,2) (-2,6) (1,3) (2,5) (8,3) (9,7)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```